# Problema con etiqueta INPUT de fecha

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

tengo un formulario que me está dando problemas en un campo de fecha y no sé qué puede estar pasando.
Si el campo lo defino de esta forma:

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" value="" id="FechaBaja" name="FechaBaja" placeholder="Fecha baja">
```

por algún motivo no me rellena el valor que le viene en el modelo, aunque cuando hago el submit del formulario sí que recibo el valor que le selecciono.
Si por el contrario lo defino así:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FechaBaja, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Fecha de baja" } })
```

Al cargar el formulario sí que me informa el valor que le viene del modelo, pero al pulsar el botón para hacer el submit, lo que pasa es que se desplega el datepicker y nada más, no me hace el post.

Estoy usando el datepicker de bottstrap, los enlaces que incluyo son estos:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundle/vendor/css/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/vendor/js/moment/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/vendor/js/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/vendor/js/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.es")
```

Edito para comentar que este problema me ocurre solo con este campo, el resto se informan correctamente.
Qué puede estar pasando o qué debería mirar?

Comment: Quizas tengas que refrescar el datepicker cuando le pasas el valor y así lo muestre bien.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu modelo, controlador y la parte del form de tu vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo he resuelto definiendo el campo así:

```
<input type="datetime" value=@Model.FechaBaja class="form-control" id="FechaBaja" name="FechaBaja" placeholder="Fecha de baja" data-val="false" data-val-required="*">
```